# Adding an Iframe to a page in ATK4

Tags: iframe, atk4

I want to know if it's possible to add an Iframe Element in ATK4 using something like `$p->add('Iframe')`.

I know Iframe is not an object, I see there is a 'Frame' class buy it's not clear for me which methods to use to set the frame content.

Comment: [This Google Search](http://www.google.com/#q=add+iframe+to+page) should give you what you need.

Comment: I don't know why the question has -3 votes ! I'm asking in ATK4 about the posibility to add an iframe using some iframe object. I'm not asking about a simple iframe in a html document. I think you misunderstood the question..

Comment: I'll reopen the question.  But you might want to be a little more specific about what you want to do.

Comment: OK, my mistake. I'm asking the question again: I want to know if it's possible to add an Iframe Element in ATK4 using something like $p->add('Iframe'). I know Iframe is not an object, I see there is a 'Frame' class buy it's not clear for me which methods to use to set the frame content. Thanks again. Alejandro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using HtmlElement

You can add any element to the page in ATK by this:

$page->add('HtmlElement')->setElement('iframe')->setAttr('src',$url);

### Using view with custom template

You can put any HTML into a file (templates/default/view/mytemplate.html) and then include it to your page:

$page->add('View',null,null,array('view/mytemplate'));

---

More info here: http://agiletoolkit.org/learn/understand/view/usage